# no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'

Tags: ubuntu, c++14, clang++

I'm using cmake 3.9.2 and I have the following lines in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall")
```

I'm also using clang 4.0 as my compiler, and my OS is Ubuntu Trusty. When I was installing clang I added the following repositories:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main
ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

and ran the commands:

```
# apt-get install clang-4.0 libstdc++6 libc++1
```

And after all I'm still getting the error

```
error: no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'
```

At the same time on my OS X 10.11 everything builds and runs smoothly. On Ubuntu Zesty I also don't have any problems. What I'm doing wrong on Ubuntu Trusty?

Comment: included `<memory>`?

Comment: @RickAstley yes, it's included

Comment: Most problable something's wrong with your CXX_FLAGS. My guess is that they link to C++11 (i.e., -std=c++11) rather to C++14 (i.e., -std=c++14) where std::make_unique was introduced.

Comment: @101010 I ran `make VERBOSE=1` and I got `/usr/bin/clang++-4.0   -I/project_path/../.  -g -Wall -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=gnu++14 -m64 -o CMakeFiles/.../file.cpp`

Comment: @CaptainRR remove the `-std=gnu++14` and `-o` is misplaced

Comment: @101010 sorry, I just pasted the command in a wrong way. `clang++-4.0 -I/project/.  -g -Wall -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=gnu++14 -m64 -o /project/file.o -c /project/file.cpp`. I tried to remove the `-std=gnu++14` but everything remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I resolved the issue. I needed to install `libc++-dev` and make sure `-stdlib=libc++` is in the command line.